# How to print from HTML5 Pages

Tags: asp.net, wpf, html, printing, clickonce

I am working on site, that need to print to the default printer(Would be nice if can pick via code from the installed printer) from an HTML5 Page.

Not only that, preferably i want the printing to be silent printing(NO selection or dialog boxes)

The application/website is used in the warehouse, and need to do lots of Label printing and shipping label printing.

I am thinking about using click Once application just for the printing part, but not sure if they have full access to the system.

Should be cross browser compatible.

What are my options, links to working example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There's almost no way to do it, short of a IE browser extension, that's going to avoid the print dialog, if your goal is to go from server -> browser -> printer.

However, if you have a network printer, and you're willing to go server -> printer, then it is possible.

I wrote up a few different solutions here: http://forum.print-dev.com/discussion/9/printing-directly-from-rails-app-to-printer#latest

Of those three (print by email, print by network protocol, print by google cloudprint), I find print by email to be the easiest by far to implement, because sending an email is pretty straightforward in most languages.